# Page reload issue on changing the route in Angular7

Tags: angular7

In my application on change of every route the whole page getting reload like when we do page refresh. That should not happen on changing of routes. I worked on Angular2, 4 5 and 6. I didn't face this issue before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue when I started work with Angular. It might be possible in your HTML page

```
<a href="">Home</a>  //Don't use this one
```

Instead of you use

```
<a class="" routerLink="/homePage" skipLocationChange>Home</a>
```

Comment: I didn't get what you mean to say "Don't use this one Instead of you use Home"

Comment: <a class="" routerLink="/Signup" skipLocationChange> Sign up</a>

Comment: dont use <a href = "Signup" > Sign up</a>